# How to set up a std::string, so that appending to it fails (or will not be observable)?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s1 = "hello ";
    string s2 = "world";
    s1.append(s2);

    cout<<s1;
}
```

I can control on `s1` value but can't control `s2` value or change/add any other introduction in this code.

What can I do so even the code use `s1.append(s2)` s2 will not append to s1. (So the output will be `hello` ) in Linux

I tried to `s1="hello \0 bbb";` but the output still was hello world.

Is there any way to fail this append?

The goal is I take `s1` and create linux file with this name so I don't want the filename contain `s2` string

Comment: What do you mean by "fail to append"? If you don't want to append, don't write that code.

Comment: No, you can't make a pre-existing function not do what it's supposed to do. If you give some more context, there might be a good alternative.

Comment: What is `end` used in `s1.append(end);`?

Comment: @cigien this is the code...I want to know if I can fail append by influence only `s1`

Comment: @MikeCAT Post edited

Comment: `s1.resize(8);`

Comment: @MarekR I can't add mote instruction to this code

Comment: Also why `8`, @Marek?

Comment: `string const s1 = "hello ";`

Comment: @user14055095 `s1` has this size at beginning so calling that after append will restore initial value.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this came from some kind of quiz.

The answer is: you can't.

With a C program you'd probably be using null-terminated buffers, and the solution would be relatively easy. But `std::string` is binary safe so there is nothing you can put into `s1` that will "break" the string or prevent an appended `s2` from being meaningful.

There may be some terminal/platform-specific tricks you can pull from up your sleeve in order to get this going at that level, when your terminal receives the data from your program via `cout`, but I can't think of any off-hand. Except for *maybe* [the EOT control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character) (but only if you're on Windows; end-of-file is signalled in a different way on Linux and macOS), depending on what you're actually doing with the output.

Comment: I use Linux , do you offer to add EOF on the end of `s1` so `s2` will not append ? How can I do that? I edit the post and add my goal

Comment: @user14055095 I don't think it will work on Linux, but you can write an ASCII EOT character (sorry said EOF before which was wrong) into a string literal with `\u0004`

Comment: I suppose you could inject some ANSI control codes to play around with text colours and things, to "hide" the appended text in the output window. But you're really getting into specifics there and so we'd need more context. The direct answer to your question remains: no, you cannot make the `append` fail.

Comment: Thank you again.look at my edit, s1 that append with s2 take to filename. I dont want that filename will include the text in s2, Is that passible?

Comment: @user14055095 I understood the question, and have nothing to add to this answer. Also, your edit removed all my clarifications that made the question easier to understand for others, which is a shame.